# Cascade remove with Spring Data JPA (bi-directional)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've got the following bi-directional relationship between two entity classes:

> **User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Set<Book> books;
}
```

> **Book**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME"),
    })
    private User user;
```

}

I want to remove a `User` with the delete cascading down to all the books associated with the user. However, when I used a Spring Data `CrudRepository`:

```
myDAO.delete(String userId) // interface extending CrudRepository<User, UserPK>
```

I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_IN88FEHUXOOYQK0YE71USPIEP table: USER
```

I was trying to use `orhpanRemoval`, all kind of `CascadeTypes` both `org.hibernate` and `javax.persistence`. I don't want to implement native queries like `@Query(Delete from User....)` I'm wondering about exception statement **foreign key no action** whether I directly specified cascade option.

Comment: How is the database schema generated? Why do you have `@Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE)` from `Book` to `User`? Surely, you don't want to delete all `User`s who have a `Book` when you delete that book (or do you), because that's what that cascade will do.

Comment: Hi @manish, i've removed cascade from Book, still nothing changed. as for schema i'm not using any of sql scripts, i'm creating LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with flag "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" that is set to "update".

Answer (score 1):

There is a many-to-one relationship from `Book` to `User`. Therefore, the `Book` table requires only a single column to capture the foreign key to the `User` table.

The code:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME"),
})
private User user;
```

should simply be:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

---

When you use the Hibernate Schema Generation Tool (`HBM2DDL`), foreign key constraints are generated as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE
  BOOK
ADD CONSTRAINT
  FK_IN88FEHUXOOYQK0YE71USPIEP
FOREIGN KEY
  (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER (ID)
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Notice `ON DELETE NO ACTION`. This means, when a `User` instance is deleted, nothing should happen to `Book` instances associated with it (`NO ACTION`). This practically means that the `User` should not be allowed to be deleted.

If you want `Book` instances associated with a `User` to be deleted when the `User` is deleted, the DDL should be:

```
ALTER TABLE
  BOOK
ADD CONSTRAINT
  FK_IN88FEHUXOOYQK0YE71USPIEP
FOREIGN KEY
  (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER (ID)
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This can be generated by adding a Hibernate-specific annotation to the domain model:

```
class User {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
  @Cascade({CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
  @OnDelete(OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private Set<Book> books;
}
```